# External Ubuntu SSD not recognized by Windows 10 PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a external SSD with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, which worked OK with a very old Toshiba with Windows 7, and other computers as well.

Now I have a Windows 10 laptop from HP and can't run Ubuntu from that SSD. Windows 10 sees the external drive as HDD. I have configured the BIOS to give priority to USB devices, which did not allow me to boot from the external.

The Toshiba Boot Manager sees the drive as a SanDisk SDSSDA120G, but the HP Boot Manager don't see the disk at all. Is this related to GRUB (version 2.02) on the external SSD?

Edit. Further Information:

- The external disk is GPT
- Windows sees the external from `diskmgmt.msc`

Comment: In Windows 10, please do `Win-R` and then run `diskmgmt.msc` then right-click on the Windows boot drive; is its partition table GPT or MBR? Can you see the external SSD from that app, and is it GPT or MBR?  Please click on edit above at left then add that information to the original question.

Comment: It may be a UEFI issue. Do you have a Live  Ubuntu UFD? If so, run `sudo parted -l` and post output in your question.

Comment: @PaulBenson It was actually a UEFI issue. When changing to legacy mode, I can run ubuntu with no problems. Thanks a lot ;)